# jQuery Tabs are not visible and scripts not loading in asp.net mvc partial view

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to show partial view in a page which i made it as layout. when i get the partial view loaded into the layout (main) page, i am unable to view tabs. only ul li and pages are continuously seen from top to bottom. I hope someone will suggest an answer to it

Answer (score 0):

on your partial view put this code:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#yourTabsID" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
```